# JQuery: Toggling hide/show div elements - Is there a more efficient method?

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I have four div elements I am toggling between:

```
<!-- Toggle controls -->
<span id="todayToggle">
    Today
</span>
<span id="tomorrowToggle">
    Tomorrow
</span>
<span id="thirdToggle">
   Third day
</span>
<span id="fourthToggle">
   Fourth day
</span>


<!-- Divs to hide/show -->
<div class="premium" id="today">
    <h3>First day</h3>
</div>

<div class="premium" id="tomorrow">
    <h3>Second day</h3>
</div>

<div class="premium" id="third-day">
    <h3>Third day</h3>
</div>

<div class="premium" id="fourth-day">
    <h3>Fourth day</h3>
</div>
```

Here is the JQuery I am using to hide/show the individual elements. The "today" div is shown by default upon page load. My aim is to simply show the selected div and hide the other three, depending on which  element is selected.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#tomorrow, #third-day, #fourth-day").hide();
    $("#todayToggle").click(function() {
        $("#tomorrow, #third-day, #fourth-day").hide();
        $("#today").show();
    });

    $("#tomorrowToggle").click(function() {
        $("#today, #third-day, #fourth-day").hide();
        $("#tomorrow").show();
    });

    $("#thirdToggle").click(function() {
        $("#today, #tomorrow, #fourth-day").hide();
        $("#third-day").show();
    });

    $("#fourthToggle").click(function() {
        $("#today, #tomorrow, #third-day").hide();
        $("#fourth-day").show();
    });

});
</script>
```

This works, but it seems really inefficient and I'm sure there is a much cleaner and practical solution to this. Any help and advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you could use jquery.ui and in particular the tabs widget, which does exactly what you want, while providing support for animation, themes,...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach, though it involves changing the `id` of the latter two `div` elements:

```
$('span[id]').on('click', function(){
    var clicked = this;
    $('.premium').hide().filter(function(){
        return this.id == clicked.id.replace('Toggle','');
    }).show();
}).first().click();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gJQ8j/3).

Alternatively, based on the `id` mapping to the text of the clicked element:

```
$('span[id]').on('click', function(){
    var clicked = $(this);
    $('.premium').hide().filter(function(){
        return this.id === $.trim(clicked.text()).toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g,'-');
    }).show();
}).first().click();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gJQ8j/4/).

Or, and probably finally, using the index of the clicked element (assuming the clicked element and the element to show share the same index):

```
$('span[id]').on('click', function(){
    var clicked = $(this);
    $('.premium').hide().eq(clicked.index('span[id]')).show();
}).first().click();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gJQ8j/5/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
  - [`String.prototype.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).
- jQuery:

  - [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).
  - [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
  - [Has-attribute (`[attribute]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/).
  - [`first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/).
  - [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
  - [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: `$('div.premium[id]:not(#today)').hide();` for div#today is shown by default

Comment: @anonymous: I...completely overlooked that part. And, since being prompted (thanks!), I chose to  infer the OP meant simply the *first*, so I took the simple approach of chaining `.first().click()` to the `$('span[id]')` selector to implement that functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I've used something like this recently:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5uEHc/1/)

Add a `data` attribute to your trigger element:

```
<span class="toggle_trigger" data-toggle-target="#today">
    Today
</span>
```

Then use that attribute to find the target. So your code would become:

```
$(".premium").hide(); /* hide all via class instead of ID's */
$('.toggle_trigger').on('click',function() {
    var target = $(this).data('toggle-target');
    $(".premium").hide();
    $(target).show();
});
```

Or a slightly shorter version:

```
$('.toggle_trigger').on('click',function() {
    $(".premium").hide();
    $($(this).data('toggle-target')).show();
});
```

Comment: I like this version! Thank you! :)